# Возможно ли вывести окно ошибки в делфи 7 без приостановки программы?

Tags: windows, delphi

Требуется вывести несколько ошибок сразу, как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Что такое `окно ошибки`? Если имеются в виду выводимые программистом сообщения в окнах, открытых модально, то ничего не мешает создать свои окошки, показав их обычным образом (не ShowModal)

Comment: я имел ввиду messagedlg()

Comment: Сделайте своё окно, да и всё.

Comment: Здесь, возможно, имеются ввиду ошибки заполнения пользователем какой-либо формы ввода данных. Можно не сразу выводить сообщение на каждой проверке поля, а завести локальную переменную а-ля `s: string`, в неё добавлять ошибки заполнения, например `s:=s+#13#10'поле ххх не должно быть пустым`, а в конце метода проверки - вывести эту переменную s

Answer (score 0):

Диалоговые окна, вызываемые для показа сообщений, не являются чем то необычным. Это просто окна c определённым стилем, вывод которых осуществлён в модальном режиме.

Так что Вы можете создать свой тип формы, определив нужный вид (в частности, `BorderStyle`), и при необходимости создавать её, и показывать с помощью `Show`, а не `ShowModal`.

Удобно также задать в `OnClose` этой формы действие `caFree`, чтобы не заботиться об освобождении, и можно обернуть всё (создание, назначение текста и т.д.) в процедуру вроде `ShowMyMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться выводом '**MessageBox**'

Например: **MessageBox(0,'Сообщение выводимое при ошибке','Заголовок окна',0);**